# sailsJS .exec() within forloop doesn't work

Tags: sails.js

i have a model something like this:

```
\**
* user.petIds = ["1","2","3","4"];
*\
getPets: function(users){
    var response = [];
    users.forEach(function(user){
      Pet.find(users[i].petIds).exec(function(err, pets){
        if(err) return null;
        console.log("index: "+i);
        response.push({ name: users[i].name, pets: pets});
      });
    });
    return response;
  }
```

I want to get every pets from an array of pet ids for an array of users. However, an exec only executes after a callback which in this case causes a return prematurely. Is there anything in Sails which solve this problem? Otherwise it's impossible to use a for loop to query. I'm still very new to the way how JS works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a Sails issue, it's a general issue with Node which you'll encounter as you learn more about asynchronous programming.  If you search StackOverflow for "node.js asynchronous loop" you'll find [dozens of questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+asynchronous+loop).  The problem is that you're calling an  asynchronous function (`.exec()`) inside a synchronous `for` loop, so all of the iterations of the loop (and the `return response`) occur before any of the actual callbacks (the `function(err, pets)` functions) are called.

The easiest way to solve this is to use a library like `async` to run the loop asynchronously.  It's for this reason that `async` is included and globalized by Sails by default, so you can do:

```
// Note the new second argument to "getPets", since this is
// an asynchronous function it requires a callback
getPets: function(users, getPetsCb){

    // Asynchronous "map" call to transform users
    async.map(users, function iterator (user, mapCb){

      // Get the user's pets
      Pet.find(user.petIds).exec(function(err, pets) {

        // In case of error pass it to the callback, which
        // will abort the loop
        if(err) return mapCb(err);

        // Use "null" as the first arg to indicate no error has
        // occurred, and pass the transformed user as the second
        // to add it to the array
        return mapCb(null, { name: user.name, pets: pets});
      });
    }, 
    // Pass the outer callback as the 3rd argument to async.map
    // to pass the final error state and array of transformed
    // users to whoever called "getPets"
    getPetsCb);
}
```

Read the [full docs for `async.map` here](https://github.com/caolan/async#map), as well as all the other fun `async` methods.

Also note that in your particular case you could use [Sails associations](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations) to model the relationship between User and Pet and get all this information with one query: `User.find(...).populate('pets').exec(...)`!

Comment: So I assume that getPets returns function(err, response)?

Comment: `getPets` returns nothing.  This is what you have to understand about asynchronous programming.  In order to process the results of what goes on in `getPets`, you have to pass in a callback function as the  `getPetsCb` arguments.  That function can be anything, but should have the `(err, result)` signature that is typical of Node callbacks.

Comment: I got that. Thanks a lot for the help. It made me understood asynchronous programming well. (:

Answer (score 2):

If you use Sails .10 or greater you can use model associations to handle this by approaching the problem a bit differently. In fact they detail a very similar use case in the [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html).

If you setup your models in this way:

myApp/api/models/pet.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        // include whatever other attributes
        owner:{
            model:'user'
        }
    }
}
```

myApp/api/models/user.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        // other attributes you may want included here
        pets:{
            collection: 'pet',
            via: 'owner'
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you can use the following to find all the pets for given users:

```
getPets: function(req, res) {
    User.find()
        .where({id: users})
        .populate('pets')
        .exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err) throw err; // do error handling here

        return res.json({
            users: users
        });
    });
}
```

By doing this the JSON that is sent back to you has each user, and all of that user's pets as shown here.

```
{
    users:
        [{ 
            pets: 
               [ { name: 'Spot',
                   id: 2,
                   createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 17:58:04 GMT-0600 (CST),
                   updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 17:58:04 GMT-0600 (CST),
                   owner: 1 },
                 { name: 'Sparky',
                   id: 4,
                   createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 18:02:58 GMT-0600 (CST),
                   updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 18:02:58 GMT-0600 (CST),
                   owner: 1 } ],
              name: 'Mike',
              createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 17:49:04 GMT-0600 (CST),
              updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 17:49:04 GMT-0600 (CST),
              id: 1 
        }]
}
```

You can then access an individual users pets using the returned JSON.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting associations. I do have associations and I would like to explore other methods. Thanks! (:

Comment: I would like to add on that joining tables would cost more than selecting. So I'm also trying to find ways to optimise the query. I hope I'm on the right track.